# Runnable JAR file error with Commons-lang

Tags: java, javafx, jar, executable, apache-commons-lang3

I have a project that involve using Commons-lang. I downloaded the bin and make the whole process of creating the User Library for adding it in another projects.

Everything works fine using Eclipse IDE, but when I want to Export the project as a Runnable JAR. The actual project starts but doesn't make the functionality related to the Commons-lang library.

When I execute it with Command line I got this errors

[Error messages from JAR file in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIJwN.png)

I'm using the option of Package required libraries into generated JAR.

I want to know what conf I have to change to make the actual Runnable JAR fully functional.

Comment: Can you show us your project structure?

Comment: When using JavaFX, you might want to check the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin), because it creates a javafx-executable with separate lib-folder containing all required jar-files :) *Disclaimer:* I'm the maintainer of that project

Comment: @FibreFoX I was trying to follow the instructions from Talon to use Maven and I look for Maven in the marketplace I have the Maven Integration for Eclipse (Luna) 1.5.0 and the same but for Luna and newer 1.5. But as I can see in the link is another thing. 

Here is a picture of the project structure [link](http://imgur.com/a/6YwYR)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Maven to build your jar? There is a plugin that can package all your dependencies in your jar.

[Excutable jar with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)